# C++ Color calculation from grayscape to color

Tags: c++, pointers, colors

I have a program that generates an grayscale image. The grayshading for every pixel is set with the following code sniped:

```
//loop over all pixel
    *PixelColorPointer = Number * 0x010101;
```

in this case the `Number` is an integer number between 0 and 255. Which generates all grayscale colors from black to white.

What I try to do is have an colored image (in order to have [false colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_color)), but I don't really understand the calculation with the hex value. I figured out if I assign e.g. `Number * 0xFFFFFF` I have a gradient/variety from white to yellow.

Can someone explain me how the calculation of this colors is working? Please remember that (as said already) I want/have to pass the `Number` variable to get variety.

Comment: `Number * 0x010101` is an elegant way of turning (say) 5 into 0x00050505 - that is, it sets r,g,b to number. What I've done in the past is calculate a 256 entry table with the desired colours in it. Your 'current table' (if one were stored instead of calculated) would be 0x00000000, 0x00010101, 0x00020202, 0x00030303 .... 0x00FEFEFE, 0x00FFFFFF. So, make a 256 entry table of 4byte integers. Set each to be the RGB of a colour, then use `Number` as the index.`*PixelColorPointer = colArray[Number]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a little more information. What library of function are you using to do this??

But by just seeing the problems I think the hexadecimal number refers to the [color](http://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp) in the Color-hex code, the **Number** would refer to the brightness 0 being blank and 255 max color intensity (white)

**EDIT:** Actually I think the whole number resulting from:

```
Number * 0x010101
```

Is the hexadecimal color code, in the particular case of *0x010101* the **Number** works as the intensity. But any other hexadecimal would give you some weird result.

Use an Color-hex code table choose any random color and just input :

```
*PixelColorPointer = 0XHEXCODE;
```

if the output is the desired color then I'm right

Answer (score 0):

RGB color are stored byte by byte (0 to 255).

When you say `0x010203` it is (in hex) `01` red, `02` green, and `03` blue. It can also be inverted (`03` red, `02` green, `01` blue) depending on your [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Here you have to separate your 3 colors. Then you shoud multiply every color by it's coefficient.

You can store your color in an union, it's the easiest way.

```
union Color
{
  struct
  {
    unsigned char b;
    unsigned char g;
    unsigned char r;
    unsigned char a; // Useless here
  };
  unsigned int full;
};

Color c;
c.full = 0x102030;

unsigned char res = 0.229 * c.r + 0.587 * c.g + 0.114 * c.b;

Color grey;
grey.r = grey.g = grey.b = res;
```

0.229, 0.587 and 0.114 are the [Relative luminance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_luminance).

Remember, you might need to invert the rgba order and move the `a` place :)